# Covering index does not show the performance as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I have two tables same structure. I added index for columns of one table and Covered index for other tales. Table structure follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'first_name',
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'last_name',
  `pin` bigint(music) NOT NULL DEFAULT '679339',
  `event_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='test db' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Added indexes for the tables using following queries

### **Table1** (Normal index)

```
alter table customer add INDEX(name)

alter table customer add INDEX(event_time)
```

### **Table2** (Covered index)

```
alter table customer_tb add INDEX(name,event_time)
```

Inserted 100 000 records in both table and run the following query::

```
"select name, event_time from customer_tb group by event_time order by event_time"
```

Query time for indexed table: 0.185sec

Query time for covered indexed table :1.29 sec.

Why the covered index is not showing the result performance as much as normal indexed table.

Query used for covering index follows:

```
alter table customer_tb add INDEX(name,event_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an index covering both columns referenced in the query, but you defined the index with the columns in the wrong order. You should define them this way:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_tb ADD INDEX(event_time,name);
```

Column order in an index matters a lot. My favorite analogy for an index is a telephone book. If I ask you to find any name in the phone book with last name "Smith" it's easy. But if I ask you to find any name with first name "John," then the fact that the book is pre-sorted doesn't help you.

Likewise if I ask you to give a list of last names and the groupwise count of how many people there are with each last name, you can do it by paging through the book and you know all the occurrences of a given last name are together. So you don't have to keep track of how many of each last name you've seen, you just count them up and when you find a different last name, you report the running total and start over.

But if I ask you to tell me the count of how many people with each first name, suddenly it's much harder, because they are scattered through the whole book. You have to keep not one running tally, but N running tallies, one for each possible first name.

Comment: Thanks.!!. I have changed indexing according to your suggestion. But, the result for covered index and normal index are almost same with 10,000 records. I expect a faster performance covered index.

Comment: I would check EXPLAIN for this query to make sure it's using the new index. And also make sure your innodb_buffer_pool_size is large enough to hold the index, because performance will be bad if it has to load the index on every query.